# Overriding model file of third party extension magento2.3.2: Type Error occurred when creating object

Tags: magento2, error, extensions, model, third-party-module

I am using amasty store locator extension. and I am customizing one of the model files of the extension.The file which i want to override is located inside Amasty/Storelocator/model/location.php. But When I am trying to override the file it is giving me this type of error. I have tried bin/magento setup:di:compile command. Tried deleting generated folder but still, this error is coming.
Thank you in advance.

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Map\Model\Location

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\RuntimeException): Type Error occurred when creating object: Vendor\Map\Model\Location
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Vendor\Map\Model\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:150]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Vendor\Map\Model\...') called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:79]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Amasty\Storeloca...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Amasty\Storeloca...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/BlockFactory.php:46]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\BlockFactory->createBlock('Amasty\Storeloca...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:268]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->getBlockInstance('Amasty\Storeloca...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:248]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->createBlock('Amasty\Storeloca...', 'amasty.locator.c...', array('data' => array())) called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/Block.php:226]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\Block->generateBlock(&Magento\Framework\View\Layout\ScheduledStructure#000000001b3442af000000003a4d0e5f#,
```

**app/code/Vendor/Map/etc/di.xml**

```
<preference for="Amasty\Storelocator\Model\Location" type="Vendor\Map\Model\Location" />
```

------------------------------------------------------------------
**app/code/Vendor/Map/Model/Location.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Map\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
class Location extends \Amasty\Storelocator\Model\Location
{
    private $escaper;
    private $configProvider;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $serializer;
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
    Escaper $escaper,
    ConfigProvider $configProvider, 
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,                            
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory 
     $productCollectionFactory,
     array $data = []) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
         $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->configProvider = $configProvider;
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $formFactory,
            null);
        }
Public Custom Function
}
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Paste Amasty\Storelocator\Model\Location constructor code too, there is the answer

Comment: I suggest you to use a try catch in your controller construct and print the real error message. Edit ; Also I think the better practice would be to call the parent construct in the first place, then make the the others ones initialization.

Comment: Yes, I haven't passed the correct parameters in constructor.Now It is solved thank you guys.